# Unity3D: Letting a BoxCollider2D collide with the floor 'earlier'?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, game-physics, gravity

## Pre-info:

I'm making a 2D game in Unity which behaves like Castle Crashers, where the player can move around forwards and backwards like in a sidescroller, but also up and down, kind of like a topdown game - but it's still a 'sidescroller'.

In Unity I'm using Rigidbody2Ds and Boxcollider2Ds for physics.
However, when wanting to simulate things like dropping items, creating gibs or any other object that needs to fall to the 'floor', this gets tricky.

The objects that need to fall to the floor don't know where the floor is, so they'll fall forever.

## Question

Can Boxcollider2Ds be set to collide with an individual infinite x-axis?
[image: Collision]

Object A should collide with the red axis and Object B should collide with the blue axis.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could use layers. And in project settings -> Physics2DSettings set them not to collide with each other. There is a hard limit of 32 layers and first 8 are used by system (you can still use them for this) this leaves you with 24 discreet layers - change layer of your objects when they change their position on Y axis. The gameplay might feel awful.
- Use 3D physics. tilt your camera 45 degrees on X axis, set projection to ortho, and draw 2D sprites on top of invisible 3D physics objects - then you will have real 2D plane to walk and jump on.
- Don't use box2d at all: write your own - simple physics library, you need it only for jumping and falling, right ?

Comment: I'm considering the 3D physics option as I'm not that far into development. Thanks.